# Handling Uniform Type Identifiers for showing to the user

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I am using Uniform Type Identifiers to get the file type of PHAssets:

```
fileFormat = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: imageAsset).first?.uniformTypeIdentifier
```

I want to show fileFormat to the user so I need to clean the returned string. But as you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1), the strings are messy and have different formats from one file type to the other. Is there any way to get only the file extensions from the UTI string or any better way of getting the PHAsset's file format without using UTI? or I just have to clean each returned string one by one?

I am looking for a way to get the true file type, not the extension included in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. It turns out not only can you get the file extension from a UTI, but you can get MIME types. The key is to use UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass with a suitable Type Tag Class. Full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1442744-uttypecopypreferredtagwithclass).

And the code I am using is this:

```
    import MobileCoreServices

    if let fileUTI = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: imageAsset).first?.uniformTypeIdentifier {

            if let fileExtension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(fileUTI as CFString, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension)?.takeRetainedValue() {

                        print("File type is: \(fileExtension)")
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `UTTypeCopyDescription`. For example:

```
import MobileCoreServices

let png = kUTTypePNG // or, for example: "public.png" as CFString
if let desc = UTTypeCopyDescription(png)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    let desc = desc as String // "PNG image"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution was another UTType function. You can check my answer.